# How to calculate image histogram of 32bit floating point image in OPenCV

Tags: opencv, histogram

I want to calculate histogram of an image hows pixels are of type 32F (32 bit floating point). What should be the parameter values of "calcHist" function for:
- dims
- bins
- range

Comment: no wait. first explain, how *you* would bin floating point data ;)

Comment: that's the problem.  floating point means values are between 0 and 1 and may be million of possible values.

Comment: There is an opencv function that map 32F Mat to unsigned char Mat. Then you could simply call the calcHist function. It will give you an approximation of the histogram that may be good enough for you.

Comment: Which function is that?

Comment: convertto : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html. You could have done a basic research to find that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I've done this many times. Something like so:

```
cv::Mat matSrc;    // this is a CV_32FC1 normalised image

int nHistSize = 65536;
float fRange[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f };
const float* fHistRange = { fRange };

cv::Mat matHist;
cv::calcHist(&matSrc, 1, 0, cv::Mat(), matHist, 1, &nHistSize, &fHistRange);
```

As it says [in the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html) describing the source arrays:

> Source arrays. They all should have the same depth, CV_8U or CV_32F ,
>   and the same size. Each of them can have an arbitrary number of
>   channels.

So CV_32F is supported. In this situation, the range (in my example 0.0 to 1.0) is binned into the number of bins required (in my example 65536).

Comment: This will have issues with images that have full-intensity pixels (ie. 1.0) because the upper range in limit is *exclusive* [per docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html). Instead, you might try `float fRange[] = { 0.f, 1.f + FLT_EPSILON };`