# Range of values of a 32FC1 opencv mat

Tags: opencv, floating-point, mat

I have an opencv mat 32FC1 but I don't understand why when I access pixel's values, the possible range returned is 0 to more than 7 000 000. It should be between 0.0 to 1.0, no ? Is there something to do ?

The context of my question :

I use a mat 32FC1 format to stack n frames together.

```
Mat final_img = Mat::zeros(960, 1280 ,CV_32FC1);
```

The frames are 16UC1, grabbed from a camera.

When I receive a new frame, I convert it in 32FC1 and add it to final_img.

```
frame.convertTo(frame, CV_32FC1);
accumulate(frame, final_img);
```

When I access pixel of the final img, I have values between 0 and 7371000.

I would to draw an histogram of this final image like here :
[How to calculate image histogram of 32bit floating point image in OPenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757702/how-to-calculate-image-histogram-of-32bit-floating-point-image-in-opencv)

But my values are not in floating point values in the range 0.0 to 1.0.
There is something that I don't understand.

Comment: please elaborate a bit. Share what u have done so far

Comment: why do you assume [0..1] range ?

Comment: frame.convertTo(frame, CV_32FC1, 1.0/0xffff);

Comment: Ok, I have edited my questions with more details about the context.

Comment: .convertTo fills the result with exactly the same element values (if possible) as the spurce elements were before but in the other type. 32FC1 can hold any float

Comment: Ok, so I just have to convert my final_img like that : `final_img.convertTo(final_img, CV_32FC1, 1.0/maxVal); `